# Apache / Nginx / Varnish - GZIP does not work on css, js

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, varnish, gzip

My current setup is as following:
Apache -> Nginx -> Varnish
running on Ubuntu

apache2.conf: h**p://pastebin.com/A3wehAbe

.htaccess: h**p://pastebin.com/Yre4hdSy (edited to allow deflate)

nginx.conf: h**p://pastebin.com/6X59CTAr (gzip enabled)

varnish: default settings

My problem is, it seems that GZIP only works with html content, not css or js.

I tested GZIP with this tool at:
http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php

1. h**p://rentsites.com.au
   result: compressed yes

   > status HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   >   server  nginx/0.7.65
   >   content-type    text/html;
   >   charset=UTF-8
   >   x-powered-by    PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22
   >   x-pingback  h**p://rentsites.com.au/xmlrpc.php
   >   vary    Accept-Encoding
   >   content-encoding    gzip
   >   content-length  2281
   >   accept-ranges   bytes
   >   date    Mon, 13 Jan 201400:50:26 GMT
   >   x-varnish   785049695 785049694
   >   age 13
   >   via 1.1 varnish
   >   connection  close
2. h**p://rentsites.com.au/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
   result: compressed NO

   > status HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   >   server  nginx/0.7.65
   >   content-type    application/x-javascript
   >   last-modified   Wed, 21 Aug 2013 15:41:10 GMT
   >   expires Mon, 12 Jan 2015 23:17:22 GMT
   >   cache-control   max-age=31536000, public
   >   pragma  public
   >   content-length  93085
   >   accept-ranges   bytes
   >   date    Mon, 13 Jan 2014 00:27:30 GMT
   >   x-varnish   785049693 785049631
   >   age 4208
   >   via 1.1 varnish
   >   connection  close
3. h**p://rentsites.com.au/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/genericons/genericons.css
   result: compressed NO

   > status HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   >   server  nginx/0.7.65
   >   content-type    text/css
   >   last-modified   Tue, 12 Nov 2013 18:38:10 GMT
   >   expires Mon, 12 Jan 2015 23:16:50 GMT
   >   cache-control   max-age=31536000, public
   >   pragma  public
   >   content-length  22680
   >   accept-ranges   bytes
   >   date    Mon, 13 Jan 2014 00:52:38 GMT
   >   x-varnish   785049696 785049621
   >   age 5748
   >   via 1.1 varnish
   >   connection  close

Please help. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hmmm, your structure: Apache -> Nginx -> Varnish looks a little confusing for me. However only Nginx and Apache are able to gzip/deflate content. Varnish is able to cache it but doesn't know about it's content. For Varnish a gzipped element and an un-gzipped element are different objects. To find the responsible application try to use your test tool against each single application (e.g. Apache is listening on port 8000, Nginx is listening on port 8080 and Varnish is listening on port 80).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we need to add this to .htaccess:

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```